# How can I install Rails on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

I'm newbie about Ubuntu.
Chromebook Pixel LS(2015)

Ubuntu 14.04 amd64 by crouton.unity

and I installed rvm 1.26.11 & ruby 2.3.0p0

How can I install the Rails??

I tried some things. but I don't have knowledge about Linux...

```
(trusty)snowcat@localhost:~$ gem install rails --version 4.2.5 --no-ri --no-rdocFetching: rack-1.6.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rack-1.6.4
Fetching: concurrent-ruby-1.0.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed concurrent-ruby-1.0.0
Fetching: sprockets-3.5.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed sprockets-3.5.2
Fetching: thread_safe-0.3.5.gem (100%)
Successfully installed thread_safe-0.3.5
Fetching: tzinfo-1.2.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed tzinfo-1.2.2
Fetching: i18n-0.7.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed i18n-0.7.0
Fetching: activesupport-4.2.5.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activesupport-4.2.5
Fetching: mini_portile2-2.0.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed mini_portile2-2.0.0
Fetching: nokogiri-1.6.7.1.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/snowcat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.1/ext/nokogiri
/home/snowcat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160108-3517-11wk1wh.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/snowcat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --help
    --clean
/home/snowcat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /home/snowcat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:571:in `block in try_compile'
    from /home/snowcat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:522:in `with_werror'
    from /home/snowcat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:571:in `try_compile'
    from extconf.rb:80:in `nokogiri_try_compile'
    from extconf.rb:87:in `block in add_cflags'
    from /home/snowcat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:629:in `with_cflags'
    from extconf.rb:86:in `add_cflags'
    from extconf.rb:336:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /home/snowcat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/nokogiri-1.6.7.1/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/snowcat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/snowcat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/nokogiri-1.6.7.1/gem_make.out
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nokogiri` wants to be built as a C extension, meaning you need build tools for the C language. Try

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

and then continue with installing rails.